# Deleting items from a list that is in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. For example:

```
dict_a = {'verbs': ['run', 'go', 'eat'], 'nouns':['dog', 'cat', 'bear']}

dict_b = {'verbs': ['jump'], 'nouns': ['human']}
```

I have written a function that can take all the items in each list from dict_b and place them into their proper spot in dict_a. (I.e., dict_b 'verbs' will go into dict_a 'verbs', etc etc...)

However I also need to write a function to take out those same words from dict_b if they are in dict_a, but I'm kind of lost. I've written a few things, but none of them worked. I'm not expecting anyone to do the work for me, but if someone has a hint give... That'd be awesome.

Comment: Your 2nd question looks a little bit confused, could you provide some example?

Comment: Maybe sets are a better fit that lists

Comment: Can you clarify the second part. If you've just added all the verbs from dict_b to dict_a and then remove all the verbs in dict_a from dict_b - won't the verbs in dict_b just be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict_a = {'verbs': ['run', 'go', 'eat'], 'nouns':['dog', 'cat', 'bear']}
dict_b = {'verbs': ['jump'], 'nouns': ['human']}

def foo(dict_a, dict_b):
  for k,v in dict_b.iteritems():
    for word in v[:]:
      if word in dict_a.get(k, []):
        dict_b[k].remove(word)
```

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for, although the last line should be dict_a, not _b, as I was looking to remove the stuff out of dict_a. Thank you.

Comment: I see now that to "take out those same words from dict_b if they are in dict_a" can be interpreted in two different ways, depending on how you read it!  But I'm glad the function was clear enough that you were able to see how to modify this code to achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the verbs/nouns isn't imporant, it's a better idea to use sets in place of yourr lists

```
>>> dict_a = {'verbs': {'run', 'go', 'eat'}, 'nouns':{'dog', 'cat', 'bear'}}
>>> dict_b = {'verbs': {'jump'}, 'nouns': {'human'}}
>>> for k in dict_a:
...  dict_a[k] |= dict_b[k]
... 
>>> dict_a
{'verbs': set(['go', 'jump', 'run', 'eat']), 'nouns': set(['human', 'dog', 'bear', 'cat'])}
```

I'm not too clear on what the second part of your question is, but it's easy to remove elements of one set from another

```
>>> for k in dict_a:
...  dict_a[k] -= dict_b[k]
... 
>>> dict_a
{'verbs': set(['go', 'run', 'eat']), 'nouns': set(['dog', 'bear', 'cat'])}
```

ie. back to the original `dict_a`

Comment: Holy crap! I just looked at the module, and this is very cool. I thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

> list.remove(x)
>
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x.
>   It is an error if there is no such item.

From the Python documentation, [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html). That might be enough, if not, I'll add some!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pop`, to remove the inspected element from the list.

Though might I suggest:

```
dict_a['verbs'] = dict_a['verbs'] + dict_b['verbs']
dict_a['nouns'] = dict_a['nouns'] + dict_b['nouns']
```

.

Another option, which may be preferable is to map the other way (and then you can `update`):

```
dict_c = {'run': 'verb', 'cat': 'noun',...}
dict_c = {'jump':'verb', 'human':'noun'}
dict_c.update(dict_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could use *dict comprehensions* to merge both dictionaries:

```
{key:dict_a[key] + dict_b[key] for key in dict_b if dict_a.has_key(key)}
```

Or, without dict comprehensions:

```
for key in dict_b:
    if dict_a.has_key(key):
        dict_a[key] += dict_b[key]
```

Removing the items from the `dict_b` dictionary is easy:

```
for key in dict_a:
    if dict_b.has_key(key):
        del dict_b[key]
```

Comment: they weren't asking about deleting the whole key-and-value, just removing select items from the value